# Springdoc OpenAPI multiple servers json

Tags: java, spring, openapi, service-discovery, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am looking into the possibility to have one central swagger UI where you can see the /v3/api-docs from multiple localhost.

My idea for this was to have multiple `GroupedOpenApi` Beans were each goes to a different localhost.
For example:

```java
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi apimicroservice() {
      String service = discoveryClient.getServices().get(0);
      return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("microservice-test").pathsToMatch(
       //Here the api-docs of the given host, example:
         "http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs"
       //Or like how I want it with eureka:
        "http://" + service + "/v3/api-docs"
      ).build();
}
```

Is this possible, maybe not with GroupedOpenApi but something else?

When I now create multiple `@Bean` for GroupedOpenApi it works but I would like it to be 1 bean with a `List<GroupedOpenApi>` but that doesn't work in my UI. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

for centralized swagger ui you will need a abstraction like api gateway at top to combine the response

ref: https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/02/20/microservices-api-documentation-with-springdoc-openapi/

whole credit to piotr for making this tutorial.

Comment: I saw his post I just don't understand how it goes from `/{serviceName}/**` to the right localhost because my services are not in 1 directory?
Is it because of his config file of the gateway with all the routes?
I would like this to be generic so that when new services are added to eureka they will be added to the swagger ui without having to change anything.
This is where I am stuck because I don't understand how it works.